# Serial cable gender

Tags: cable, serial

What is the gender standard of a serial connection?

Seems that all computer's serial ports are male, but it is ambiguous the peripheral gender... I see printers with female DB9 connectort and also male DB9 connector.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe there is a standard.  It entirely depends on the device itself.

Comment: Does not depends on DTE/DCE role?

Comment: I don't think the answer can be better than [that wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Connectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the gender standard of a serial connection?

Both. You need a male and a female end to couple.

> Seems that all computer's serial ports are male, but it is ambiguous the peripheral gender...

That is common, but by no means a rule. It is not a standard per se, just more of a convention. In computers, like everything else, people are really resistant to change things that have been around for a while if they work well enough.

> I see printers with female DB9 connectort and also male DB9 connector.

And that is why gender-changers, -couplers, and -adapters exist. There is nothing in the format itself that requires it to be male or female, ultimately “it’s all pipes”… well wires.

Comment: Thank you... so if I need to build a new peripheral I can choose whatever I want.

Comment: As long as it physically fits and the wires inside match-up, yes. Years ago, I deigned and built a parallel device and only had to look up the pinout of the parallel port and the get a cable that had a female connector. After that, I could connect up the cables as desired (or rather, as the parts I had at my disposal dictated).

Answer (score 0):

Up to some years ago, there was no standard in serial devices.
For this reason, I was equipped with a small bag with:

- DB9/25 gender adapters;
- DB9/25 converters;
- DB9/25 tester (a box with jumpers ad switches to test any available configuration of wires)
- DB9/25 shelves with removable/configurable wires (both male and female).

It's a bit frustrating being in the desert of Algeria, after 3 hours of travel, trying to plug a serial cable into a PLC to flush new software and discover that you pick the wrong cable...